# Evaluating Infinite Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]Having some trouble understanding infinite series,

Here's an example:
$1-\frac 1 2 +\frac 1 4-\frac 1 8+\frac 1 {16}...$

I can come up with the sigma notation for $a_n$,

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac {1} {2^n}$

I understand that the answer is $S_n=\frac {1} {1-x} = \frac {2}{3}$ because it's a geometric series, but what I'm trying to figure out is $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$, where $S_n$ is the sequence of the sums $S_1,S_2,S_3,...S_n$, but I can't figure out what $S_n$ is as I'm being asked to represent it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}$of [$S_n$], and then evaluate.

I'm having more trouble with understanding the broader concept of "the sum of an infinite series is the limit of its partial sums" and coming up with an expression for $S_n$ when I'm given something like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(\frac {x} {x+3})$ for example, I see that it's convergent as $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$, but when it comes to finding an $S_n$ and then evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ I'm completely lost.

Any help with the understanding **(not just answers to the examples)** would be appreciated!

Comment: $1-\dfrac12+\dfrac14-\dfrac18+\dfrac1{16}-\dfrac1{32}+...=\dfrac 12+\dfrac18+\dfrac1{32}+...$ is a geometric series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general formula for a geometric sum $\sum_{k=0}^n aq^k$ is $a\frac{\left(1-q^{n+1}\right)}{1-q}$. Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\left(-\frac12\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(-\frac12\right)}=\frac{1-0}{\frac32}=\frac23$$,
since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac12\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{2^n}=0$$.

Also, you shouldn't be too worried about not always finding the formula for the partial sum. In many cases the partial sum is very complicated, but there is an easy way of evaluating the sun in the limit.

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<1$, the geometric series is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x},$$ in your example $x=-1/2$, so $$S_N\rightarrow \frac{2}{3}$$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$.

The partial sums are $S_N=\sum_{n=0}^N x^n = \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$ and thus here
$$S_N=\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{(-2)^{N+1}}\right)}{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3(-2)^N} $$ is the finite-$N$ correction for large $N$.

Comment: I understand that part and the formula for a geometric series, but I'm looking to represent it as $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ with an expression for $S_n$ using $n$.

Answer (score 0):

We have the general formula for the sum of a geometric series with $\;|q|<1\;$ :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n=\frac1{1-q}$$

so your series sum is...

Comment: I understand the cut-and-paste formula for evaluating the geometric series, but I'm struggling with understand the concept of $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ so that I can apply this to other questions like $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln(\frac {n} {n+3})$ like I mentioned above